# Event listener for table cell in JS

Tags: javascript, events, click, target

here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o2764sst/
After one clicks on cell, which contains radio button (or checkbox) I want this radio button (or checkbook) to be selected and this cell to change color. How can I access clicked table cell? I've tried by event.target.nodeName

```
document.getElementsById("konfiguruj-produkt").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.nodeName);
});
```

}

, but it returns more detailed info. Is there any way I check, if clicked element is cell with input or as a parent has a cell with input?

Comment: Looks like you've a non-native method in your srcipt: `getElementsById()` is what?

Comment: @Teemu, it's just a typo - should be getElementById()

Answer (score 0):

I saw jquery in your code. Try to use him.

```
 $("input[name=licencja]").change(function(event) {
        $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","red");
    });
```

see your code

http://jsfiddle.net/o2764sst/2/

Comment: it gives error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"